# Как правильно в Android приложении распарсить Json?

Tags: android, java, json

Android приложение получает с сервера Json-ответ на запрос.
Ответ сервера имеет следующий вид:

при выводе в консоль

```
System.out.println(response);
```

Ответ сервера имеет следующий вид:

```
["test2","test1"]
```

или такой (не знаю, как удобнее):

```
[{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test1"}]
```

Как правильно сделать парсер для добавления значений в String[].

**Обновление**

[[@Gorets](/users/3608/gorets)](/users/3608/gorets), В php файле обращаюсь к базе с запросом на выборку из таблицы "Tests", достаю из неё все значения поля "name". Далее мне нужно сформировать Json со значениями "name", отправить на Android и распарсить.

Как правильно создать Json, хранящий в себе все значения "name"?

Comment: Использовать библиотеку GSON или аналоги.

Comment: Вообще неправильная структура json.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    String str=jsonArray.getString(i); // Если это массив строк
    JSONObject obj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); //Если это объект
    String str2=obj.getString("name"); // Получаем строку из объекта
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать библиотеки GSON или LoganSquare, которые могут оборачивать ваши классы и парсить JSON в них. Вручную парсить JSON не нужно. Обычно используются вместе с классами DAO. Вы пишите аннотацию и библиотека сама парсит. На выходе готовый класс Java.

Библиотека-открытие для меня: https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare