# Как десериализовать/распарсить json?

Tags: java, android, json

От сервера поступает такой ответ

```
{
films: [{
name: 'film1,
score: 1,
date: '2005-03-24'
}, {
name: 'film14',
score: 3,
date: '2011-12-24'
}
}]
}
```

Нужно десериализовать эти данные и записать в бд (2 уже знаю)

Comment: Это не `JSON`. Этот *текст* не соответствует стандартам `JSON`

Comment: Исправил, теперь вроде больше похож на `JSON`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш json не правильный, он должен быть таким (проверить правильность можно тут http://json.parser.online.fr/)

```
{"films":[{"name": "film" ,"score": 1, "date": "2005-03-24"}, {"name": "film14", "score": 3, "date": "2011-12-24"}]}
```

Добавьте в

```
gradle dependencies
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
```

затем создайте класс, описывающий вашу модель

```
public class Model {

 public ArrayList<Film> films;

    public static class Film {
        public String name;
        public int score;
        public String date;
    }

}
```

А потом можно все это дело распарсить таким образом

```
String jsonString = "{\"films\":[{\"name\": \"film\" ,\"score\": 1, \"date\": \"2005-03-24\"}, {\"name\": \"film14\", \"score\": 3, \"date\": \"2011-12-24\"}]}";

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Model model = (Model) gson.fromJson(jsonString, Model.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

на примере Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ClassForBD classForBd = mapper.readValue(string, ClassForBD.class);
```

, где `ClassForBD` - это в ваш класс, в который будет "заходить" десериализация. Его необходимо предварительно создать с нужными полями и аннотациями. `string` - собственно сама строка с сериализованными данными. (есть перегруженный вариант для `Reader`'а)

Answer (score 1):

На основе [Как правильно в Android приложении распарсить Json?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/370016/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json?rq=1) решил еще так:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString);
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String str1=obj.getString("name");...}
```

ps тут без импорта сторонних библиотек (вроде как) и без создания класса